# Solaris 11 apps running as root are not themed

Tags: themes, gtk2

Hi Im running Oracle Solaris 11.3 with a theme I made. It works fine for most of the gtk2 apps. However, I noticed that apps runninng as root dont get themed!

How can I apply my theme to the apps running as root?

Comment: It looks like the apps are not running as root. Sorry, they are Java apps

Comment: (<unknown>:25868): Gtk-WARNING **: ld.so.1: java: fatal: /usr/lib/amd64/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/engines/libmurrine.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32

Comment: Looks like the murrine theme engine needs to be 64bit right?